# Why is my parser showing errors for valid programs?

Tags: flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I can't figure out what's wrong with my parser. Here are the associated files:

parse.y

```
    declarations:     INTEGER_SIZE IDENTIFIER TERMINATOR {declare($1,$2);}

    void yyerror(char *err){
        printf("\n\nYYError on line %d: Error = %s\n", yylineno, err);
    }
```

scan.l

```
[Xx]+                       {yylval.size = strlen(yytext);
```

When running it against the valid program below it shows an error at line 3; when running any of the lines individually it shows an error on line 1 via the `yyerror()` function.

```
BEGINING.
XXX XY-1.
XXXX Y.
XXXX Z.

BODY.
PRINT “Please enter a number? ”.
INPUT Y.

MOVE 15 TO Z.
ADD Y TO Z.
PRINT XY-1;” + “;Y;”=”;Z.

END.
```

To run the files run the following commands:

1. yacc -d parser.y
2. lex lexer.l
3. gcc -o  parser lex.yy.c y.tab.c -ll

Comment: Exceptions are thrown. Compiler errors are printed. The word you are looking for is 'program', not 'language instance'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This non-terminal is called `declarations`, from which one might think that it matches one or more declarations, or perhaps zero or more declarations:

```
declarations:       INTEGER_SIZE IDENTIFIER TERMINATOR {declare($1,$2);}
```

But the rule matches exactly three tokens, which is to say one declaration. So when you give it an input with two declarations, it fails on the second one.

Similarly, your non-terminal called `statements` only matches a single statement, not several as might be expected from its name.

Grammars need to be explicit. If you want to match several declarations, you have to write that:

```
declarations: declaration
            | declarations declaration
```

By the way, I have seen before grammars written with the belief that you have to write `{;}` at the end of a production. I'm curious where this idea comes from. Yacc and bison do not require that productions have an action, and anyway an empty action is `{}`, just as it is in C.

Comment: You're a life saver! still have more work to do on it based on your suggestions to get it to work but that helped alot! Many thanks man!